# Insert Image in RichTextBox with XAML property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want insert a image into the RichTextBox control in WP7/8.

I can do it in XAML and it work fine.

```
<RichTextBox>                  
       <Paragraph> 
           <InlineUIContainer>
               <Image Source="/ApplicationIcon.png"/>
           </InlineUIContainer>
       </Paragraph>
  </RichTextBox>
```

I can do it in code C#:

```
        Image MyImage = new Image();
        MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        MyImage.Height = 50;
        MyImage.Width = 50;
        InlineUIContainer MyUI = new InlineUIContainer();
        MyUI.Child = MyImage;

        Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
        myRichTextBox.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);

        myParagraph.Inlines.Add(MyUI);
```

But I can't do this way.

```
        string xaml =
                @"<Section xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">
                    <Paragraph>                   
                        <InlineUIContainer>
                             <Image Source=""/ApplicationIcon.png""/>
                        </InlineUIContainer>
                    </Paragraph>                                 
                </Section>";
        myRichTextBox.Xaml = xaml;
```

I have the error. [image]

I read about it [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/setting-richtextbox-xaml-via-code-in-windows-phone-solution) :

> That is happening because the XAML parser does not know how to resolve
>   the Paragraph, Underline, etc. elements. In order to fix this, the
>   paragraphs with the actual content must be wrapped in a Section
>   element that defines the namespace so that the elements can be
>   resolved!

But `<Section xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"">` don't help.

This is not my whim, for me really easy to create content this way. (I use StringFormat, Replace, etc).

In what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

From [this article](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-dynamically-generating-datatemplate-in-code):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListBox list = new ListBox();
    list.ItemTemplate = this.CreateDataTemplate(); 
    list.ItemsSource = new List<string>{"first","second","third","forth"};
    ContentPanel.Children.Add(list);
}

private DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate()
{
      string xaml = @"<DataTemplate
                            xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
                            xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
                            <Grid>            
                                <RichTextBox IsReadOnly=""True"">
                                    <Paragraph>                                      
                                        <InlineUIContainer> 
                                                <Image  Source=""https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0UAA.jpg?s=32&g=1"" /> 
                                        </InlineUIContainer>
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </RichTextBox>            
                            </Grid>        
                            </DataTemplate>";
       DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);  
       return dt;
   }
```

Exception   `"System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException"` in line:

```
 DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to assign image using Xaml Property of RichTextBox. Refer the below link regarding to elements can be included with the Xaml Property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.xaml(v=vs.95).aspx

If you want to design it dynamically using a list, you can create a DataTemplate Dynamically as given in below link.

http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-dynamically-generating-datatemplate-in-code

Your Template can be like this:

```
      @"<DataTemplate
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
    <Grid>            
        <RichTextBox><Paragraph><InlineUIContainer> <Image Height='50' Width='50' Source='/RichTextBoxBinding;component/Desert.jpg' /> </InlineUIContainer></Paragraph></RichTextBox>            
    </Grid>        
    </DataTemplate>";
```

Comment: thank for you answer! I checked the link. But with image it don't work, please check update my post.

Comment: replace <Image  Source=""http://i.stack.imgur.com/m0UAA.jpg?s=32&amp;g=1"" /> .   Xaml does not allow "&" directly. So you have to use &amp;